# Remotely SSH into home computer that is connected to a VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

I have a computer at home that is connected to a PIA VPN. I've been trying to figure out how to remotely ssh into that computer while it is connected to the VPN using port forwarding provided by PIA, but I cannot figure out the correct way to specify the SSH command. I'm fairly certain it is possible because I remember figuring it out once a while ago, but I can't seem to remember how I specified it and have been trying to figure out what arguments I should be passing.

First I tried this:

`ssh user@LocalVPNIP -R 22:PublicVPNIP:FPort`

where PublicVPNIP is the public IP that is assigned to my computer from the VPN, LocalVPNIP is the private IP that is assigned to my computer from the VPN, and FPort is the port that the PIA client says it is using for port forwarding. What is the correct way to specify the ssh command for this?

Comment: What do you mean port forwarding provided by PIA? Does your VPN provider allow you to direct connection to Internet address? I suspect not, have you tried something like this: `ssh -L 22:yourserverip:22 user@publicvpnip` then in another shell `ssh user@127.0.0.1`?

Comment: The PIA client has a setting to allow port forwarding (though it only works when connected to specific subset of the available VPN connections). The client then displays the port that is forwarded to the computer that is connected. Which IP are you referring to when you say "yourserverip"? I assumed you meant the private VPN IP address, but that did not work. 127.0.0.1 still connected back to my localhost.

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken then. Please ignore me :).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are confusing port forwarding through `ssh` (`-R` switch) with port forwarding provided by VPN. I do not know PIA at all. If the PIA client says that *FPort* is forwarded to your computer's port *22*, then my guess is:

```
ssh -p FPort user@PublicVPNIP
```

Comment: tried this as well, it just hangs.